# trouble passing argument from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having issues with passing an argument from a directive to a controller. The argument "compoundID" keeps coming back undefined. Im using angular js. I plan to have more then one of the directives per page.

JS:

```
angular.module('ireg').directive('compound', function () {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{             
        compoundID:'='
    },
    templateUrl: '/ireg/components/compound/compound.html'
};
});

angular.module('ireg').controller("compoundController",['$scope','$attrs','compoundService', function($scope,$attrs,compoundService ){
    var vm = this;
    vm.compoundID = $attrs.compoundID;
    console.log($attrs);
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "compound-view" ng-controller = "compoundViewController as controll" > 
<compound compoundID="{{controll.compoundID}}"></compound>{{controll.compoundID}}
<div = "studies" ng-repeat="study in controll.studies">
    <studie studyID="{{study.ID}}"></studie>
</div>
<cro croID= "{{croID}}"></cro>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're declaring scope like this:

```
scope:{             
    compoundID:'='
},
```

You're simply telling that the `compoundID` attribute should be treated as a model to be automatically parsed by Angular. You should use the model directly, so instead of:

```
<compound compoundID="{{controll.compoundID}}">
```

write:

```
<compound compoundID="controll.compoundID">
```

If you wanted to write `<compound compoundID="{{controll.compoundID}}">`, your scope should be declared like this instead:

```
scope:{             
    compoundID:'@'
},
```

**Also** mind that Angular translated `aSampleAttribute` ("camel case") in your directive's definition to `a-sample-attribute` (em… "kebab case"??) to be used in html. So I think that if you have `compoundID` in directive you *may* have to write `<compound compound-i-d="………">`.

I know it's nasty, so I'd suggest you use sth like `compoundId` => `compound-id` instead.

Comment: "Kebab case" perfect.

Comment: Unfortunately the object I've being given still doesn't have the argument. Do you know a possible source for that error?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how what is the purpose of the controller you've put in the question. Do you intend for it to be a directive's controller? I'd be best if you provide a minimal setup demonstration of how this part of app should be constructed, on http://plnkr.co/ - I will be able to fix it there.